# google.script to make folders in google drive with part of file name and then move files

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to move files that are all present in one google drive folder to folders that are of the file names.

The files are of two formats, `.psd` and `.jpg`. I need a `google.script` that will read the file name, make a folder of part of that file name and move all files that start with that file name into that folder regardless of the extension.

For example, if I have 12 files named as

```
082234567_CI.psd
082234567_pic.jpg
082234567_pic2.jpg
082234567_pic3.jpg

082234568_CI.psd
082234568_pic.jpg
082234568_pic2.jpg
082234568_pic3.jpg

082234569_CI.psd
082234569_pic.jpg
082234569_pic2.jpg
082234569_pic3.jpg
```

I need a google.script that will make folders `082234567`, `082234568` and 082234569 and move all the respective files into the respective folders.

So, files 082234569_CI.psd, 082234569_pic.jpg, 082234569_pic2.jpg, and 082234569_pic3.jpg will be in folder named 082234569 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want easily using the following functions in an Apps Script:

1) To get the folder where you have the files use getFolderById [1]

2) Apply getFiles [2] or getfilesbytypemimetype [3] functions to the Folder object to retrieve all the files inside it.

3) For each file use makeCopy [4] function to copy them into your destination folder and also getName function [5] to get the name.

4) Create a folder with createFolder function [6].

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFolderById(String)

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder.html#getFiles()

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder.html#getfilesbytypemimetype

[4] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(Folder)

[5] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getName()

[6] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFolder(String)